# Send using POST a web FORM to another page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, post

I have a web page with a `HTML` form and a submit button

```
<form id="prodottoSingle">
    <button id="nelCarrello">ADD</button>
...
</form>
```

onClick this jQuery

I want post to another page with POST request (not GET).

What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#nelCarrello").click(function() {
    var IDprodotto = 9999;
    var idgusto = 14;
    var finalqt = 20;
    var MyData = 'ID=' + IDprodotto + '&Gus=' + idgusto + '&Qt=' + finalqt;
    $("#prodottoSingle").post('Comands/CMD_Test.asp', myData);

    $("#prodottoSingle").attr('action', 'Comands/CMD_Test.asp?ID=' + IDprodotto + '&Gus=' + idgusto + '&Qt=' + finalqt);

});
```

Comment: Hi Alen, I think you are missing a quote or a quote is disturbing your code around `+ finalqt';`. This last quote seems not to have an ending quote, or is a typo.

Comment: Hey my friend, do use console (google chrome -> inspect element) to debug first and see any errors. I think data should be array not "string" like you are used to when "sending" a GET request.